# Java Separate Input of Two Separate Keyboards

Tags: java, usb

I have two USB keyboards plugged into the same machine. I am developing a Java application. Is there anyway to allow the Java Application to separate out which USB keyboard it came from? (I.e. is there something like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html but with a USB parameter so I can know which USB device it came from?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible with Java alone.

But there are 3rd party tools that can remap the keys of a keyboard. [HID macros](http://www.hidmacros.eu/whatisit.php) is one application. But it only works with key presses, not key-up and -down events. This limits it's usefulness but might be enough for your usecase.

If you want to dig deeper you need to use the [RAW Input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows to do what you want. There's already a nice example on code project titled [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard) that sheds some light on the correct API usage.

Comment: I would up vote this answer, but I lack the 15 reputation to do so.

Comment: Haha, that's ok. Thanks for accepting it. Hope the solution works for you.

Answer (score 4):

I might be too late to answer here since this question is an old one. But since I have been directed here when I was looking for the same requirement, I will mention a solution I found on another thread for the help of those who will be directed here in the future, seeking help for the same requirement. @nan has given a solution for this using the java-hid-api and you can find his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17210694/3127619). He has also written a clear and step by step post on how to do it [in his blog](http://nanlee.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/manykeyboard-using-java-hid-api-to-handle-multiple-keyboard-input/).

However I must say that I have tried this but still I haven't been successful at it as the `HIDManager` returns null when trying to open the HID by either the path or the id. It is the same when tried to `open()` using `HIDDeviceInfo`. This issue is listed in the [java hid api page](https://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/issues/list?cursor=javahidapi:21) too but it seems no one has been able to provide a working solution so far. So if there is anyone who has been able to bypass this issue. Please do share.

Comment: If you are running on Windows then the reason you cannot open HID keyboards is because the OS opens all HID keyboards for its *exclusive use*. See this MSDN article for reference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. According to the README for a different Java HID implementation the workaround to the above problem is to bypass HID and go to the lower level USB API.  https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java.