# Is there a Java/C library which allows identify multiple keyboards?

Tags: java, c, macos, keyboard-events, keyboard-hook

I need to connect more than one keyboard/mouse with a single computer. Manymouse library can identify different mouses, but is there a library which can identify different keyboards?

I mean, when I press Key "E", the program can tell me which keyboard the KeyPress event is from. With C#, the SDGToolkit can do it, is there something in the Java world or C world, which supports all OS just as Manymouse does? I am more interested in Mac and Linux solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know the solution. I can use a hid library to detect different keyboard. Here is an explanation :
http://nanlee.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/manykeyboard-using-java-hid-api-to-handle-multiple-keyboard-input/

Comment: This link does not exist as of today. Could you update to where it is?